# PostgreSQL: Can't log into Postgres - sudo broken?

Tags: postgresql, macos, sudo, macos-high-sierra

Hey so after I ran into somes issues I decided to uninstall Postgres and re-install it (re install a newer version btw).

I'm trying to access postgres to create a new db for my Rails app so I run `su postgres`or `su _postgres` then I am asked a password but nothing that I enter works.

So I tried `sudo -u postgres psql` and got

```
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I tried also to disable SIP (see: [here](https://www.imore.com/how-turn-system-integrity-protection-macos))

but it didn't work either. same results.

I don't know what to do. Any idea ? I am using Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: What about `sudo -u _postgres psql`?

Comment: thank you @GordonDavisson the password works ! however, I then get: `psql: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist`. What's wrong ?

Comment: Try: `psql  -u postgres`

Comment: @wildplasser thank you for you help; it says `psql: invalid option -- u`

Comment: Oops, that should have been a capital U: `psql -U postgres`

Comment: @wildplasser now I get `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to @gordon Davidson and @wildplasser 's help, I found the solution:

`sudo -u myusername psql postgres`

Comment: alternatively: `psql -U myusername -d postgres` without the need for sudo

Comment: I am having the same error, Could you please help me what i am suppose to do right? 

sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: @MushahidKhan did you run the above mentionned command to try and solve your issue ?

Comment: @JulesCorb, obvious, i tried , but not table to log in, working on it, hopefully will get some solution

Answer (score 2):

I had this same challenge when trying to access a PostgreSQL database.

When I run the command below:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I get the error below:

```
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

The issue was that I did not have the PostgreSQL database server installed on the server. The server only had a MySQL database server set up on it.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

From your EC2 node issue the following command to test if database is reachable.

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -U YourExistingUsername -d template1 -h AWS-RDS-POSTGRES-ENDPOINT
```